# Iterate over json result and get the desirable data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a json result which I am trying to convert into dataframe but not able to get the correct result. Actually for some cases it is giving correct but for some case it is failing.

Example:

Based on metric API is generating result for specified interval. But this is not certain for that particular interval metric have output or not. And process is running 4 different queue_id.

suppose process is running only for 2 metric. ['nOffered', 'nTransferred']

queue_id = 'a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3'
for this queue_id, nOffered is having some values but nTransferred doesn't have. Json result is given below-

```
queryResult: {'results': [{'data': [{'interval': '2021-10-11T11:46:25.000Z/2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 1,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None},
                       {'interval': '2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z/2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 2,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None},
                       {'interval': '2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z/2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 3,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None},
                       {'interval': '2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z/2021-10-16T11:46:25.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 1,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None}],
              'group': {'mediaType': 'voice',
                        'queueId': '73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155'}}]}
```

My code is giving below output-

```
                   queue_id            nOffered_count  nOffered_sum       interval_start   interval_end                       
0  a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3   6         None        2021-10-11T11:46:25.000Z  2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z
1  a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3   1         None        2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z  2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z
2  a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3  12         None        2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z  2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z
3  a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3   6         None        2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z  2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z
4  a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3   6         None        2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z  2021-10-16T11:46:25.000Z
```

But when process is running for 2nd queue_id that time it is not working-
queue_id - 73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155

json output for this queue_id -

```
queryResult: {'results': [{'data': [{'interval': '2021-10-11T11:46:25.000Z/2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 1,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None},
                       {'interval': '2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z/2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 2,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}},
                                    {'metric': 'nTransferred',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 1,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None},
                       {'interval': '2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z/2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 3,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None},
                       {'interval': '2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z/2021-10-16T11:46:25.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 1,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None}],
              'group': {'mediaType': 'voice',
                        'queueId': '73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155'}}]}
```

This time both metric having some data. So output would be-

```
Queue_Id,Interval Start,Interval End,nOffered_count,nOffered_sum,nOffered.denominator,nOffered.numerator,nTransferred_count,nTransferred_sum,nTransferred.denominator,nTransferred.numerator
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2021-10-11T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z,1,,,,,,,
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,2,,,,1,,,
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,3,,,,,,,
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-16T11:46:25.000Z,1,,,,,,,
```

And in final result, both the result merge and give the output with all columns and data.

```
Queue_Id,Interval Start,Interval End,nOffered_count,nOffered_sum,nOffered.denominator,nOffered.numerator,nTransferred_count,nTransferred_sum,nTransferred.denominator,nTransferred.numerator
a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,2021-10-11T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z,6,,,,,,,
a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z,1.0,,,,,,,
a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,12.0,,,,,,,
a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,6.0,,,,,,,
a72dba75-0bc6-4a65-b120-8803364f8dc3,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-16T11:46:25.000Z,6.0,,,,,,,
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2021-10-11T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-12T11:46:25.000Z,1,,,,,,,
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2021-10-13T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,2,,,,1.0,,,
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2021-10-14T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,3,,,,,,,
73643cff-799b-41ae-9a67-efcf5e593155,2021-10-15T11:46:25.000Z,2021-10-16T11:46:25.000Z,1,,,,,,,
```

Currently I am running below logic-

```
        out = defaultdict(list)
        
        if(query_result.results != None):
            for item in query_result.results:
                #data_lst = []
                for lst_data in item.data:
                    print("####################################")
                    print(lst_data)
                    print("####################################")
                    
                    out['queue_id'].append(queue_id)

                    for met in lst_data.metrics:
                        out[met.metric+"_count"].append(met.stats.count)
                        out[met.metric+"_sum"].append(met.stats.sum)
                        out[met.metric+".denominator"].append(met.stats.denominator)
                        out[met.metric+".numerator"].append(met.stats.numerator)
                    interval = lst_data.interval.split('/')
                    out['Interval Start'].append(interval[0])
                    out['Interval End'].append(interval[1])
                    print("out", out)
        else:
            metric_name = query.metrics[0]
            out['queue_id'].append(queue_id)
            out[metric_name+"_count"].append('')
            out[metric_name+"_sum"].append('')
            out[metric_name+".denominator"].append('')
            out[metric_name+".numerator"].append('')
            interval = query.interval.split('/')
            out['Interval Start'].append(interval[0])
            out['Interval End'].append(interval[1])

        print(out)
        df = pd.DataFrame(out)
        print (df)
        return df
```

Comment: Could you add your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ndclt Hi I added my code also.

Comment: Please suggest me what I need to change in my code.

Comment: Th.e given code does not work. There is at least two undefined variables `query` and `queue_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I used below logic to get the desirable result. It is working for me.

```
        lst_of_metrics = ["nOffered", "nTransferred"]
        out = defaultdict(list)
        
        if(query_result.results != None):
            for item in query_result.results:
                #data_lst = []
                for lst_data in item.data:
                    print("####################################")
                    print(lst_data)
                    print("####################################")
                    
                    out['queue_id'].append(queue_id)
                    for met1, met in itertools.zip_longest(query.metrics, lst_data.metrics):
                        if(met):
                            if(met.metric == met1):
                                out[met.metric+"_count"].append(met.stats.count)
                                out[met.metric+"_sum"].append(met.stats.sum)
                                out[met.metric+".denominator"].append(met.stats.denominator)
                                out[met.metric+".numerator"].append(met.stats.numerator)
                            else:
                                out[met1+"_count"].append('')
                                out[met1+"_sum"].append('')
                                out[met1+".denominator"].append('')
                                out[met1+".numerator"].append('')
                        else:
                            out[met1+"_count"].append('')
                            out[met1+"_sum"].append('')
                            out[met1+".denominator"].append('')
                            out[met1+".numerator"].append('')
                        
                    interval = lst_data.interval.split('/')
                    out['Interval Start'].append(interval[0])
                    out['Interval End'].append(interval[1])
                    print("out", out)
        else:
            metric_name = query.metrics[0]
            out['queue_id'].append(queue_id)
            out[metric_name+"_count"].append('')
            out[metric_name+"_sum"].append('')
            out[metric_name+".denominator"].append('')
            out[metric_name+".numerator"].append('')
            interval = query.interval.split('/')
            out['Interval Start'].append(interval[0])
            out['Interval End'].append(interval[1])

        print(out)
        df = pd.DataFrame(out)
        print (df)
```